# The work of the "giants" vs textbooks

Tags: history-of-philosophy

From a historical perspective Socrates, Plato, Aristotle, Epicurus or even the more "modern" ones like Descartes, Bacon, Nietzche etc. are very important, but aren't philosophy textbooks today way more valuable to read and learn from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a false dilemma; nobody is required to choose to use exclusively one or the other.

A serious study of philosophy is impossible without reading the primary texts.

A reading of the primary texts is impossible without sufficient context, which is most easily acquired via secondary (or tertiary) texts.

I have never heard of an undergraduate philosophy course that did not rely on a combination of the two.

Comment: But wouldn't most of the concepts developed by Aristotle and most other philosophers from pre-1900 have been elaborated on and refined by some modern philosophers?

Comment: @QuestionAnswers: Yes, but that does not mean that there is not significant value in reading the original texts; in fact, a reading of these modern philosophers is fairly impossible without an engagement with the earlier texts.  You're not going to be able to understand Heidegger without reading Husserl, and you're not going to understand Husserl without reading Kant, etc.  Naturally, since you can't read everything, you need to rely on secondary literature to fill in the gaps, and provide context along the way.  My question to you: where is your question coming from?  Why are you asking?

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I figured that the branches of philosophy had been pretty much categorized to the point where if you were to read about empericism, you would not go to Bacon, but to a textbook about empericism?

My reason for asking this question is that I want to dwelve deeper into philosophy but I am not sure where to begin. Which books of the "giants" do you recommend?

Comment: Well, the best place to begin is with a course; having a teacher available to answer questions is invaluable.  If that is not possible, I'd start with some general philosophy textbooks, and histories of philosophy, to get an overview of the major problems and trends.  As for primary texts, you can always start with some of the shorter works: some shorter dialogues of Plato, Descartes's Meditations, etc.-- but this will depend on your particular interests.

Comment: Also, there's a lot of cultural interpretation laid on top of the original work; reading the original with little preconception, you might get a different perception of them.

Comment: Since many people are reading these "original" texts in translation, it's even more muddied than you make out… The translator has already moved some way to making the original text into a "textbook" in the interpretational work necessary for a good translation.